# Powershell - passing variable into loop for string with quotes

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to understand how to setup my script so that single quotes will wrap around my variable. I have a list of 1500 customers I need to repeat my script for, so my thought as to do a foreach loop.

```
$customerlist = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT [CustomerNo] FROM [TABLE]" -ServerInstance "SERVER\INSTANCE"
#Loop through 
foreach ($customer in $customerlist)
{
    $inputParams = @{
      "CustomerNo" = "'"+$customer+"'";
    }
....Do rest of script
}
```

I need the $customer variable in my $inputparams to show with the string value in single quotes, e.g. '01233456' instead of just 0123456. I've tried several different iterations of "'"+$customer+"'" but cannot seem to get the correct syntax. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Looks okay.  Is it that you are losing the leading 0s?  Are you getting back int or string from `invoke-sqlcmd`.  Without seeing more of "Do rest of script" it's hard to tell where you are having an issue.  `"'"+$customer+"'"` should do what you want or `"'$customer'"`

Comment: @Daniel The rest of my script is to print SSRS reports to PDF. I pass CustomerNo as a parameter to the report so that the SSRS only runs 1 customer at a time. If I hard-code a customer # into PowerShell, "CustomerNo" = '0123456'; it runs just fine. But using the $customer values from the initial query (even if I modify the query to list 1 result) seems to break the script.

Comment: as an alternate method ... take a look at the `-f` string format operator. this >>> -f Format operator - PowerShell - SS64.com — https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html

Answer (score 2):

`Invoke-Sqlcmd` returns `[System.Data.DataRow]` type objects with the field name(s) and value(s) of your query result as its properties (basically a table). To select the value in the CustomerNo, you must specify the value by name:

```
# Expand the CustomerNo property to strings
foreach ($customer in $customerlist.CustomerNo) { }

# Or, later in the script:
$inputParams = @{
  CustomerNo = "'$($customer.CustomerNo)'"
}
```

Comment: @Capt.Whale That appears to be working now!  My users added a request to drop the reports into their own folder.  "later in the script" I set t$baseFolder = "\\NetworkShare\CustomerReports\" .  How Might I grab "SalesPerson" from $customerlist. I tried; $baseFolder = "\\NetworkShare\CustomerReports\"+$Customerlist.SalespersonNo+"\"  but it is crating a folder with all of the SalesPersons name's combined instead of 1 folder for each.

Comment: @Capt.Whale : disregard the previous, I got it working after another hour of tinkering.